# SAML artifact resolution service error

Tags: single-sign-on, windows-server-2012, adfs, artifact

I created one SSO service to interact my personal SP with IdP that i configured on Windows Server 2012. I could easily log in to the IdP but when my SP sends Artifact Request to IDP it couldn't be processed at IdP's side and I get following error:

```
    A SAML request for the required artifact was rejected because the artifact resolution service is not enabled. 
    Relying party: microsoft:identityserver:sp.abcd.com 

    This request failed. 

    User Action 
    Enable the artifact resolution service. 
    Use the AD FS Management snap-in to configure or enable the SAML artifact resolution endpoint.
```

Then in ADFS Management I enabled artifact resolution end point service but still I can't resolve this issue. Please suggest if any configuration I am missing.

I also get exception as:

```
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.ArtifactResolutionService.ArtifactRequestedFromDisabledServiceException: MSIS3114: SAML request for relying party trust 'microsoft:identityserver:sp.abcd.com' required artifact and was rejected because artifact service is not enabled.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.EndpointResolver.FindSamlResponseEndpointForAuthenticationRequest(Boolean artifactEnabled, AuthenticationRequest request, ScopeDescription scopeDescription)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.GetResponseEndpointFromRequest(SamlRequest request, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, ScopeDescription scope)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```